# More than one field constructor in play framework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using the twitter bootstrap as a field constructer like this

```
    @import helper.twitterBootstrap._
    @implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(extra.twitterBootstrapInput.f) }
```

How would I go about adding/using another field constructor?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one in the template, although you may be able to hack it.

First of all let's understand the code. The code you show creates an `implicit` (as the name starts by Implicit) variable called `fieldConstructor` in the resulting Scala code. As it has the type `FieldConstructor`  (automatically inferred from the value assigned) it will be used in those places where an implicit `FieldConstructor` may be needed.

If you where to declare another var of the same type in a similar way, Scala would not know which implicit to use and would raise an error.

That said, you could explicitly declare the `FieldConstructor`as in:

```
 @input(field, args:_*)( Htmlcode)(implicitFieldConstructor)
```

Notice the 3rd parameter is made explicit.

That should allow you to create more constructors like the following:

```
 @implicitAnotherFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(anotherConstructor) }
```

Warning: I could not fully test this right now, but given the way templates behave that seems your only choice.

Comment: What I do is have my regular `@implicitFieldConstructor` for the field constructor which will get used the most on the template. That will be the default one used for most field helpers. I then declare any other FieldConstructors without "implicit" in the name and pass them to any field helpers that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I figured out of going about this is adding if else statements inside one field constructor, for example in your form:

```
@inputFile(
     nsForm("plateFiles"),
 '_label -> "Upload files",
 'uploadwidget -> "Select file(s)"
)
```

and in your field constructor:

```
@if(elements.args.contains('uploadwidget)){
    //Do something here
}else{
    //Do something else
}
```